# How To Update A Widget from Another Widget with A DropDown in Flutter and Dart?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have two separate stateful widgets. One is a dropdown with values and one is a widget I would like to update `onChange` of the **DropDown**. My issue is that the second widget does not update whenever the dropdown is changed. Below is my full code.

**Dropdown Widget**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DropDownList extends StatefulWidget {
  List<String> values;
  String select;

  DropDownList({
    Key key,
    this.values,
    this.select,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DropDownListState createState() => _DropDownListState();
}

class _DropDownListState extends State<DropDownList> {
  List<String> dropdownValues = [
    "2021",
    "2020",
    "2019",
    "2018",
  ];
  var selectedValue = '2021';
  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      widget.values = dropdownValues;
      widget.select = selectedValue;
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
      child: DropdownButton<String>(
        value: selectedValue,
        icon: SizedBox.shrink(),
        // iconSize: 24,
        elevation: 0,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        selectedItemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
          return dropdownValues.map((String value) {
            return Text(
              value,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            );
          }).toList();
        },
        underline: SizedBox.shrink(),
        onChanged: (String newValue) {
          setState(() {
            selectedValue = newValue;
          });
          showJojo(selectedValue);
          print(selectedValue);
        },
        items: widget.values.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: value,
            child: Text(
              '${value}',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.deepPurple,
              ),
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }

  static showJojo(String select) {
    return Jojo(
      select: select,
    );
  }
}
```

**Second Widget To get the data**

```
class _JojoState extends State<Jojo> {
  String select;
  _JojoState(this.select);
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: new Text(
        '${this.select}',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction, please?
Amicably
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You need to add didChangeDependencies() method here, here if that variable will change page will be compiled.

````
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    setState(() {
      if (selectedValue != null) return;
    });
  }```
````

Comment: Hey there @Mustafa. I tried your code but with no success. Can you be more specific on your code? Thanks.